# Is there a way to map a temp table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to sync two SQLite databases with EF Core. To do this I have a lot of data manipulation that needs to be tracked. I can't do this with EF Core because of memory issues (about 5 million records for each database).

So I was thinking about trying to save sorted and changed data into temp tables for the processing. Then pull the data out to save all back to the databases once processing is complete. Another option is to save to XML list on disk.

Any help, advice, best practice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could use stored procedure, or just [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

> Entity Framework Core allows you to drop down to raw SQL queries when
>   working with a relational database. This can be useful if the query
>   you want to perform can't be expressed using LINQ, or if using a LINQ
>   query is resulting in inefficient SQL being sent to the database.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

However, do note there are many limitations

Comment: Thank you general. I am currently using raw to create and read from the temp table. Since it seems like efcore doesn't play nicely with temp tables. I was just hoping to get around all the raw SQL to read and write from those tables.   `var table = _contextSource.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Create Temp Table Test AS Select * From TypeList;");
var data = _contextSource.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Select * From Test;");`